How Does This Diode Affect This Circuit?
I am learning about electrical engineering and have a question about this circuit.

I don't have a very niche question, I'm just wondering how the circuit is affected by the addition of the LED.
You can find the information for the LED, if you need it, here:
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Lumileds/L128-RED1003500000?qs=T3oQrply3y%252B1vChfkdiUBA%3D%3D

Depending on the circuit before the LED (open or shorted across the LED location) there will either be 0 A or about 200 mA. After the LED is inserted as shown, there will be anywhere from 100 mA to 130 mA, which will also be present as an LED current. That's within the LED specs. The resistors before will dissipate about 0.5 W each (or try to), assuming the LED is shorted out, and will dissipate about 0.2 W each, with the LED in place. The LED will dissipate about 250 mW.

I explain to the closers: This is a variant of the 19th century Ohm's circuit with two resistors in series powered by a voltage source where a 21st century device - an LED - is inserted. The OP wants to know what has changed in this circuit.  For clarity, they have attached device reference data.

The LED is a diode which allows current to flow in one direction, but not the other as long as you don't apply enough voltage to cause breakdown in the reverse direction.
When current is flowing in the forward direction, diodes have a forward voltage drop. Common silicon diodes have a forward voltage drop around 0.6 to 0.7 V. LEDs have a higher voltage drop which is dependent on the diode. The diode you listed has a forward voltage drop of 2.1 V when 120 mA is flowing through the diode as shown on page 6 of the data sheet. On page 17, the forward voltage drop versus current is shown in graph 4b.
For the circuit you show, you can approximate the current flowing through the diode if we assume the voltage drop across the diode is 2.1 V.
$$ I_{D1} = {V1 - V_{D1} \over R } = {{5-2.1} \over 24} = 120.8\; mA$$
The above equation is an application of Ohm's law.
The LTspice simulation below shows what happens when you change the voltage of V1. Below 1.5 V the LED does not conduct. Above 1.6 V is starts to conduct and gives a fairly constant voltage drop of around 2 V. The x-axis of the graph shows V(in) which I changed by right-clicking on the x-axis and changing the quantity plotted to V(in).


Good answer... You have described very well what the LED does, but how would you explain in the simplest possible way how it does it?
